# How to catch "naked" modifier keys in urwid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, event-handling, urwid

New to GUI programming and event loops etc. so please bear with me.

Have a look at this small example. My goal is to switch focus on press of the `ALT` key.

```
import urwid

class MainWindow(urwid.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        header = urwid.LineBox(urwid.Edit(''))
        body = urwid.LineBox(urwid.Edit(''))
        super().__init__(urwid.Filler(body), header)
    def unhandled_keypress(self, k):
        if 'meta' in k:
            self.focus_position, = {'body', 'header'} - {self.focus_position}
            self.focus.base_widget.set_edit_text(k)
            return True
    def run(self):
        urwid.MainLoop(self, unhandled_input=self.unhandled_keypress).run()

mw = MainWindow()
mw.run()
```

This works ok if I press `ALT` together with a regular key but when I press `ALT` alone it is passed on to the terminal emulator containing the python process which is rather annoying usability-wise.

Is there a way to catch a "pure" modifier key?

Comment: [urwid doc](http://urwid.org/manual/userinput.html#keyboard-input) says "Not all keystrokes are sent by a user’s terminal to the program". I guess pure `Alt` is one of these keystrokes that are not sent.

Comment: @Sanyash good point, thanks. Do you happen to know a way of testing this?

Comment: This looks stupid but... the doc says "Urwid will report any keys that are sent", when I run your program `Alt` is not reported, so it is some kind of testing this. Can't propose anything better, sorry.

Comment: @Sanyash, no, not stupid. You are probably spot on. I just was not sure `urwid` will report everything it sees through this particular interface.